# How to increase shards using Vitess

Tags: mysql, scale, vitess

I have 4 shards in 4 different physical server. 
-40 40-80 80-c0 c0-
Now I want to add two more shards. How can I change key range and split the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vitess you have split or merge existing shards. You do this by creating the target shards and migrating data from existing shards into the targets. This tutorial shows how to split shards: https://vitess.io/docs/user-guides/horizontal-sharding/.

Comment: thank you for your quick response. Is there a way to automate this process?

Comment: @SajMan Vitess doesn't automate parts that require provisioning of new hardware. This is because those are very platform specific. You can use kubernetes for facilitating those, or a hosted solution like PlanetScaleDB. But once you've provisioned, it's down to a handful of commands.